# Prevent Duplicate Inserts SQL in PhpMyadmin

Tags: sql, database

I have a Table called `users` which structure looks like this:

```
user_id
google_id
google_name
google_email
```

When I try to insert a record to this table I need to check both `user_id` and `google_id` for duplicate data. When we take one by one these two columns I should be able to insert data with out an issue. I mean that a record can contain the same value in one of `user_id` or `google_id` already in the table. But not in both. I tried many things an still could not make this work. Can some one guide me? I am using Phpmyadmin to mange DB

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique index on the two columns:

```
create unique index users_ids on users(user_id,google_id)
```

If someone tries to insert another row with the same `user_id` and `google_id`, the unique index will cause an error.

Comment: do I have to make both user_id and google_id to primary keys?